# Create multiple files in C automatically

Tags: c

Im using C to solve a coupled ODE system of 12 equations (I need to use C for external reasons). Im exporting the data to a .dat file using fprintf but now I need to solve this system for different values of my parameters and i dont want to create different files manually.
Does anyone knows how can I create different .dat to store the different solutions i get for the different values of my parameters?

Sorry for my english and thanks!

Comment: You can `fopen` pretty much any filename you want.  Can you explain your question more specifically?

Comment: I need a way to create automatically different files with different file names like:   results1.dat results2.dat results3.dat etc..

Comment: `fopen` and `sprintf`

Comment: the idea is to have a for(i=1; i<3, i++){
*create a file with a name automatically
fprint(filename, results)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
FILE *files[numfiles];
for (int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++)
{
    char filename[20];
    sprintf(filename, "results%d.dat", i);
    files[i] = fopen(filename, "w");
}
```